# How can I deploy a report project and access reports in a C# application, switching between dev, test and production?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a C# project, which queries a database in SQL Server, and invokes a web browser for connecting to URLs of reports deployed on a SSRS server. Currently the database has three copies, respectively for development, test and production environments.

I was wondering how to deploy a SSRS report project for development, test, and production environments of the C# project? Is it to manually change the data source of the data set used by the reports, between the development, test, and production databases, before deploying the report project to a different directory on the reporting server?

The C# project currently hard-codes the URLs of reports on the SSRS server. Reports for dev, test and production will have different paths in their URLs. If I switch running the C# application between dev, test, and production, how can I make it switch using the report URLs for dev, test and production, without manually changing the C# code?

Comment: Configurations/transformations. What version of .net?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.2. @chief